# bash echoing value to process, php loop (the process) not reading stdin

Tags: php, linux, loops, server, command

### Background:

I'm in a position where I'm placing data into the command line and I need a php loop (what will become a server of sorts) to read STDIN and just echo what it reads to the shell its running in.

The following terrible code works when the process is running in the same shell as the content echoed:

```
<?php

echo getmypid();
$string = "/proc/" . getmypid() . "/fd/0";
while (true) {

    fwrite(STDOUT, fgets(fopen($string, 'r'), 4096) . " worked\n");

}

?>
```

I've tried many variants:

```
<?php

echo getmypid();
$string = "/proc/" . getmypid() . "/fd/0";
while (true) {

    $fo = fread(STDIN, 1024);
    fwrite(STDOUT, $fo);

}

?>
```

The problem is that whenever I write to this loop from a separate terminal, the output appears in the other terminal but is not processed by the loop.

When I enter text in the same terminal, the text is echoed right back.

I need a way to get command line data into this loop from any source.

Comment: How are you writing to it from a separate terminal?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in PHP? The standard `cat` command reads from its standard input and writes to standard output.

Comment: Barmar! Good to see you again. 

From a separate window:  `echo foo > /proc/{pid}/fd/0` . Sure enough, the output appears.

Comment: This PHP loop will eventually become a server that is listening to a port and writing to sockets a la websockets for push notification. I'm having a separate process issue its output to the command line. Thus, I would like to have that other process pipe its way into my php loop.

Comment: Writing to that FD doesn't put input into the terminal.  FD 0 is connected to that window's terminal, so you're writing *output* onto the terminal.

Comment: A terminal window's standard input is connected to a pseudo-tty. To send input to it, you need to write to the master end of the pty.

Comment: But if this will eventually become a server, the architecture of terminal windows doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: Use a named pipe. The script reads from the named pipe, the clients do `echo foo > /path/to/pipe`

Comment: Fantastic! I'll get cracking on the documentation for that. Thanks again!